# how to use Graphviz to draw a node pointed by an arrow?

Tags: plot, graphviz, dot

I use dot language to draw a simple graph which contains only one node and an edge point to this node. I came up with a way to do so:

```
digraph dot {

    n0 [label= "", shape=none]

    n0 -> n1

}
```

[image]

This implementation create a blank in the top of graph. So how to remove this blank? In other words, are there any better implementation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I came up with another better solution, which is setting the "none" node to a point. Hope you guys provide a more elegant way.

```
digraph dot {

    n0 [label= "", shape=none,height=.0,width=.0]

    n0 -> n1

}
```

Comment: `height=0,width=0` (without the decimal points) gives the same result for me (i.e. without the blank)